# x11vnc | ssvnc 'ReadExact: Socket error while reading'

Tags: linux, encryption, ssl, xorg, vnc

I have a `x11vnc` (http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) server running.

If `encryption = 0` everything is working as expected and I can connect to the server via `TightVNC Viewer` without any problems.

If `encryption = 1` I have to use `SSVNC` (http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html) to connect to the server. The client is successfully connecting, fetching the certificate, but then it fails to connect.

The `x11vnc` is running inside of this `Docker container`:
- https://hub.docker.com/r/dcflachs/veracrypt-gui/ (https://github.com/dcflachs/docker-containers/tree/master/veracrypt)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**System:** Windows 10 64bit

**Software:** ssvnc_windows_only-1.0.30.zip (http://ssvnc.sourceforge.net/dev/ssvnc_windows_only-1.0.30.zip)

Answer (score 0):

[SSVNC] is a VNC viewer that adds encryption security to VNC connections.

While the Linux version of [SSVNC] works well, the Windows version has some
issues.  At the time of writing, the latest version `1.0.30` is not functional,
as a connection fails with the following error:

```
ReadExact: Socket error while reading
```

However, for your convienence, an unoffical and working version is provided
here:

https://github.com/jlesage/docker-baseimage-gui/raw/master/tools/ssvnc_windows_only-1.0.30-r1.zip

The only difference with the offical package is that the bundled version of
`stunnel` has been upgraded to version `5.49`, which fixes the connection
problems.

Source: https://github.com/jlesage/docker-handbrake#ssvnc